# scala found Unit required Unit.type

Tags: scala

I have the following:

```
object T {
  abstract class First {
    def doSomething= (s:String) => Unit
  }

  class Second extends First {
    override def doSomething = {
      (s:String) => ()
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    new Second().doSomething
  }
}
```

but this fails to compile with the error:

```
Error:(8, 21) type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Unit.type
      (s:String) => ()
```

Why isn't the override from class Second valid? How could I make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `(s:String) => Unit` is returning `Unit.type` - instead change it to `(s:String) => ()` (or to a method if you didn't mean to be returning `Function1[String, Unit]` from your method.)

To put it another way:

```
def doSomething = (s:String) => Unit
```

is really:

```
def doSomething: (String) => Unit.type =
  // A function that takes a string and returns the companion type of Unit
  (s: String) => Unit
```

While what you *probably* wanted was:

```
def doSomething: (String) => Unit =
  // A function that takes a string and returns Unit
  (s: String) => ()
```

Or maybe:

```
def doSomething(s: String): Unit
// An abstract method that takes a string and returns nothing.
```

Comment: Surely the `Unit` companion doesn't justify the confusion. I don't actually know why the unit value syntax `()` is not an alias for it. Does SIP-23 make it easier to affirm that `Unit.type` and `().type` are the same thing in that case?

Comment: *Justify*, no - but for someone who is confusing `T1 => T2` in type position with `(v: T1) => r: T2` in value position I think `String => ()` vs `(s: String) => () // Is really ().type` would be more confusing.  (Unless I am mis-understanding what you mean).

Comment: Sorry that my comment wasn't directly about your good answer. Yes, you understood me: I can't wait to write `def f(): () = println()`, tongue in cheek. (It doesn't compile.) For now, just eliminating Unit object would avoid incidental complexity; and I wanted to express sympathy for OP.

Comment: Ah - that makes sense now, and I totally agree!  Thanks for following up!

Comment: @SeanVieira sir can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004737/how-to-call-this-objects-methods-in-a-map

Answer (score 2):

`(s:String) => Unit` returns `Unit.type` ie it returns the type rather than a value of that type. You want to do `(s:String) => ()`, which will return a value, whose type is Unit.

Comment: That's not accurate. Unit.type is the type of Unit's companion object, and the only value of `Unit.type` is the unit companion `Unit`.

Comment: It's not entirely inaccurate, either. (the i.e. is not precise.) hash tag conversations one should not be required to have.

Comment: @manojlds sir for below code  i am getting //Error  1. '=>' expected but ']' found.  2.identifier expected but ';' found. Can you please help me to fix it

Comment: val s:String = "yes"
 val myFuncs: Map[String,(String) => () ]=  Map(  //Error  1. '=>' expected but ']' found.  2.identifier expected but ';' found.
           "string2" -> (() => ProcessorTwo().process(s)),
          "string3" -> (() => ProcessorThree().process(s))
        )
   myFuncs.values.foreach(v => v());
  }

Comment: See below answer section for complete code ...sorry to place in answer section

Comment: @manojlds sir can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004737/how-to-call-this-objects-methods-in-a-map

Answer (score -1):

```
' trait Processor0 {
  def process = (x:String) => () 
}
case class Processor2() extends Processor0 {
  override def process = (x:String) =>  println("Processor2 x :" + x)
}
case class Processor3() extends Processor0 {
  override def process = (x:String) =>  println("Processor3 x :" + x)
}
object DemoProc2 {
  def main( args : Array[String]):Unit ={
  val s:String = "yes"
 val myFuncs: Map[String,(String) => () ]=  Map(  //Error  1. '=>' expected but ']' found.  2.identifier expected but ';' found.
           "string2" -> (() => ProcessorTwo().process(s)),
          "string3" -> (() => ProcessorThree().process(s))
        )
   myFuncs.values.foreach(v => v());
  }
} '
```

Comment: This answer surely could use some more explaining - how are you addressing the problem, what was supposed to happen, etc.