# How to call this objects methods in a map?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**Problem :**    I have to call Objects methods which stored in a map, for a given key how to do it ?
**Code :**

```
trait Processor00 {
  def process(x:String): Unit
}
case class Processor20() extends Processor0 {
   override def process(x:String): Unit = println("Processor20 x :" + x)
}
case class Processor30() extends Processor0 {
   override def process(x:String): Unit = println("Processor30 x :" + x)
}
object UnitTest1 {
  def main( args : Array[String]):Unit ={
    val s:String = "yes"
    val myFuncs: Map[String,(String) => Unit ]=  Map(  
           "string2" -> Processor20().process(s), //Eroor 1. type mismatch; found : Unit required: String ⇒ Unit
          "string3" -> Processor30().process(s)
        )
   myFuncs.values.foreach(v => v());//how to call all  Objects' i.e.  process("Hi") here ???
  }
}
```

Comment: @jrook , sir created a new ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Processor20().process(s)` is called a function `process` and return `Unit`

but `Processor20().process` is a function that you could save in map

Try something like:

```
trait Processor00 {
  def process(x:String): Unit
}
case class Processor20() extends Processor00 {
  override def process(x:String): Unit = println("Processor20 x :" + x)
}
case class Processor30() extends Processor00 {
  override def process(x:String): Unit = println("Processor30 x :" + x)
}


object Main extends App {
  val s: String = "yes"
  val myFuncs: Map[String, String => Unit] = Map(
    "string2" -> Processor20().process,
    "string3" -> Processor30().process
  )
  myFuncs.foreach { case (key, f) => f(s) } // or f(key)
}
```